# Cockney wh-dropping

Tags: british-english, dialects, pronunciation-vs-spelling, accent

[The Cockney accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockney#Cockney_speech) typically, or at least stereotypically, drops the initial `/h/` from many a word. Does it drop the initial `/h/` from *who*, *whole*, *whore*, and *whose*? Wikipedia says yes, but I seek a more reliable source.

---

*Edit* to clarify: I'm seeking not anecdotal evidence or impressions but a citation to someone who's collected data, such as a linguist who's studied London speech.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The spelling (and for that matter also the etymology) is essentially irrelevant in the pronunciation of those words, and other WH- words with initial /h/.  Sound changes apply to ***sounds***, not spellings.

Hence, any lect that drops initial /h/ will drop it on these words, too. I can't tell you anything about Cockney lects in particular, but linguists have known for over a century that sound change acts with blind necessity, as the Neogrammarians put it.

Comment: Many thanks. Although my question seeks a citation to a source, I'll consider a professional of your eminence such a source himself and accept this.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that *who-* words are pronounced with varying degrees of aspiration in all accents and that there is no consistency. Certainly, *Oo you talkin’ to?* or *Ooz ‘ouse is that?* would not be unusual in many parts of Britain.

Comment: On a different point:  How freqently is "that" said as "zat" in Britain in examples like *Ooz ‘ouse is that?*?

Comment: @jwpat7: I wouldn't like to say. It would require considerable research to know for sure, but I suspect a sentence like 'Is that all you have to say?' might frequently be realized as 'Izat all you have to say?' In cricket, when a batsman is perceived to be out, the appeal to the umpire has always been 'Howzat?' (How's that?')

Answer (score -1):

This link will download [“ANALYSING LINGUISTIC ATLAS DATA: THE (SOCIO-) LINGUISTIC CONTEXT OF H-DROPPING”](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiyk8Kpx7mDAxUmUEEAHXj_DCoQFnoECA4QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.raco.cat%2Findex.php%2FDialectologia%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F242110%2F324722%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3Dlook%2520at%2520%27H%252Ddropping%27%2CIt%2520is%2520one%2520of&usg=AOvVaw2M_Og4QeB0q3nJqWJBfgM8&opi=89978449) [by]Heinrich RAMISCH, University of Bamberg, which includes

> H-dropping has frequently been analysed in sociolinguistic studies of British English and it can indeed be regarded as a typical feature of working-class speech. Moreover, H-dropping is often cited as one of the features that differentiate ‘Estuary English’ from Cockney, with speakers of the former variety avoiding ‘to drop their aitches’. The term ‘Estuary English’ is used as a label for an intermediate variety between the most localised form of London speech (Cockney) and a standard form of pronunciation in the Greater London area.